# Specific ansible jump host configuration

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

Hadn't found a way to create inventory in ansible with a connection over 2 jump hosts. Normally I do create two jumps:

- ssh -L 1261:localhost:1261 user1@jump.host.ip -p 22
- then ssh -L 1262:target_host.addr user2@jump.host2.ip -p 1261
- then I connect to target host ssh user3@localhost -p 1262

No googled results and no ansible manual gived a receipt or even the explaining how to repeat this, assuming we had to keep three different users and three different passwords in inventory (even if it was vault).

All I found is:

1. use ssh config (but I couldn't use common ssh config and couldn't point ansible to use custom file instead of it)
   [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938794/need-to-use-ansible-to-connect-to-a-host-via-a-jump-host-using-a-key-in-the-jump)
   [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966782/how-do-i-configure-ansible-to-jump-through-two-bastion-hosts)
2. use ansible.cfg (but I have a plenty of playbooks for different projects and it's not a good idea)
3. use ProxyCommand (but there's no examples or manual about 2 jumps)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408017/ansible-with-a-bastion-host-jump-box

Comment: Not answeres the question, the same as previously mentioned

Comment: Related: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966782/how-do-i-configure-ansible-to-jump-through-two-bastion-hosts

Comment: @Zeitounator, I'd Mentioned it myself as "not my situation" in a post

Comment: Ho sorry, I really thought your situation was to connect thought 2 jump host in a row. My bad. Meanwhile, note that connection issue for ansbiel are off-topic on SO as also reminded in the ansible tag description.